# Getting IGNORED after running FitNesse Script

Tags: fitnesse

I am getting IGNORED message after running my FitNesse script. Though I don't see any failure getting IGNORED message. Why do we get this message? Can someone please help in this.
Thanks in advance.

**Assertions: 26 right, 0 wrong, 9 ignored, 0 exceptions**

Comment: are you using decision table? and if possible, please paste the piece of test code that gives you "ignored" result and tell us which part is ignored.

Comment: Is this a single test, or a suite? IGNORED does not mean failure that is ignored, it means test (e.g. a `check` in a Slim script) without expected result, or a test table not having any success or failure cells.